# vimrc: execute multiple lines only for certain filetypes

Tags: vim

There are a few lines in my .vimrc that I only want to use for certain file types (HTML in my case)

Currently it looks like

```
autocmd! FileType html set matchpairs+=<:>
autocmd! FileType html abb <div> <div><CR><\div><up><CR><TAB>
autocmd! FileType html abb <span> ...etc.
```

I was wondering, if I really need to retype the first part every time, or something like

```
autocmd! FileType html[
    set matchpairs+=<:>
    abb <div> <div><CR><\div><up><CR><TAB>
    abb <span> ...etc.
]
```

Comment: You can try defining a function and mapping the auto-cmd to running that function only

Comment: @BigMike Great. Took my a while to figure it out, but I think I got it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim's "filetype" mechanism already handles your needs gracefully so you don't have to pollute your `vimrc` with filetype-specific stuff.

If it doesn't already exist, create `$HOME/.vim/after/ftplugin/html.vim` (on Unix-like systems) or `$HOME/_vimfiles/after/ftplugin/html.vim` (on Windows) and put the following content:

```
setlocal matchpairs+=<:>
abbreviate <buffer> <div> <div><CR><\div><up><CR><TAB>
abbreviate <buffer> <span> ...etc.
```

Note that…

- you don't need autocommands anymore,
- `:help :setlocal` is preferred over `:help :set`,
- `<buffer>` is added to your mappings and abbreviations to prevent them from leaking to other filetypes, see `:help :map-<buffer>`.

See `:help filetype`.

Comment: great, thanks. I only recently started using vim and tinkering with my vimrc so stuff like this really helps a lot.
I would assume I should reserve `autocmd! FileType` for stuff that applies to a lot of different filetypes, where it's impractical to a dozen duplicate lines across different filetype.vim files then?

Comment: I can see two reasons to bypass the canonical method with autocommands in your `vimrc`: 1. a perceived need to have all of your stuff in a single file, 2. the scenario you describe.

Comment: Oh, one last question. I discovered that to make my abbreviations work properly I need the Eatchar function from `:helpgrep Eatchar`. Where's the best way to put that? I could put it in `html.vim` but I'll probably want to use it for other filetypes in the future so the `.vimrc` would be a better place. But in the spirit of not polluting that, is there an easy way to maybe make a dedicated file just for functions and drop it in there?

Answer (score 0):

Use `\` for line continuation and `|` to separate commands.

```
autocmd! FileType html
    \ set matchpairs+=<:>|
    \ abb <div> <div><CR><\div><up><CR><TAB>|
    \ abb <span> ...etc.
```

See `:help :bar` and `:help line-continuation`.